Making symbolic link for many files from various source dir to their corresponding destination dir


Hi all:
I am an bioinformatician and I have over 1000 trio-wes families seq data stored. Now I want to make soft links to each fastq.gz file in src dir (including father mother and patient him/herself) into my newly created dir-system. Is there a way to do it in batch?
What I know so-far is that
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3

can print out the 3rd lv files, then I have no further idea

I am sorry for that misunderstanding, it's my fault, I said batch means a bundle. I know I am using Linux. I should re-phase it into a bundle of files spread in many directories. o(╥﹏╥)o
I just edit it, thanks for your pointing out.

Please show a sample of directory structure you have. And a directory structure you want. If you know how to manually do a desired links for one file - please show it also.

Hi White, thanks for your coming. I have both figures posted above!

For formatting the code in your question, see here.  For solving your problem, the most general (and easiest to debug) way is to add to your find the clause -exec DO_LINK {} ';',  where DO_LINK would be a program (shell script or any other language), which creates the link for exactly one file. The first parameter to this script will be the path to the file. With this approach, you can easily test your code on a single file before performing the operation on your whole directory tree.

@R.L. the Researcher – I'm sorry, but your unconnected figures give me no idea what you want to be linked where.

How are the source directories like 12195 related to the destination directories like chi001
